# Bitcoin Script Execution - Must end with just `true`?

Tags: script

When executing bitcoin validation scripts, does the final stack have to end with just `true` on the stack, or can there be some elements under the `true`? In other words, are both of these final stack configurations valid, or just the first?

Stack1:

```
true
```

Stack2:

```
0 {pub_key} true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Quoting Bitcoin wiki:](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script)

> A transaction is valid if nothing in the combined script triggers failure and the top stack item is true (non-zero).

[From the source code:](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/25cc1cf8dc03b9ba0ae886d354855adc207b5b6e/src/script/interpreter.cpp#L993)

```
if (CastToBool(stack.back()) == false)
    return false;
```

(In case you don't know what vector.back() does, [it returns the last item](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/back/).)

Comment: They really coded up `== false`?

Comment: @djechlin CastToBool only returns true or false.

Comment: I think djechlin was surprised they didn't do if (!Cast... Or just return CastTo...