# How come an `OP_3` P2SH redeem script is spendable?

Tags: script, transaction-verification, p2sh, output, opcodes

I completed a round trip transaction with the redeem script hash: `31vFvEkyAb2iusbPip36H9rVt6pxExuaVR`, whose redeem script is `OP_3 (0x53)` (yes I know not secure).

I can understand `OP_1` redeem script unlocking its P2SH UTXO as 1 is left on the stack after redeem script execution, but with `OP_3`, 3 is left on the stack. So how does this successfully execute?

Tx: `36ca5aede94112009621bda42b3e84f49f7aa45886837d1d51c6590a04fcb8e7`

Comment: Related question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/100413/for-a-redeem-script-to-satisfy-the-conditions-of-a-script-what-must-it-leave-on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A script execution is successful if it ends with a non-empty stack whose top element is not 0. Therefore, a script consisting of only `OP_3` will be successful.

You may also be interested in the topic [*“For a redeem script to satisfy the conditions of a script what must it leave on the stack post execution?”*](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/100413/5406) which describes the criteria for successful scripts in more detail (H/T Michael Folkson). I would recommend [using testnet or signet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17553/5406) for experimental transactions.

Comment: Yes this is very helpful, thanks. However a P2SH redeem script of say, 3 OP_3s (535353) fails with error "Stack size must be exactly one after execution" because it is valid, but non-standard, and hence would have to be submitted to miner directly. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, stacks with more than one remaining element are non-standard for P2SH, and consensus invalid for segwit outputs.